# How is gas calculated when running my token's mine function?

Tags: mining, gas

Let's say I have a token contract, which has a mine/pow function (doing some math calculations to find a number/hash) in it. If a user hosts a geth node and runs `token.mine()`, will those math calculations be counted as gas consumption?

Please help advise, thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, you have to pay for the gas consumption of every operation executed during a transaction.

The exact price depends on the executed instruction. Some operations are cheap like adding two numbers, others are expensive like storing a non zero numbers in the contract storage, and others depends on the size of the parametesr, like calculating a hash.

This repo https://github.com/djrtwo/evm-opcode-gas-costs has a spreadsheet with the opcode values.

Comment: Thanks @Ismael for your answer! In such case, is it more practical to move calculations offchain and only send answer back afterward? My intention is to reward a user who solves the latest puzzle, and my concern was about the total gas cost for doing it onchain.